# removing all nodes in existence

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In my game, I have a method bringing down sprites. When the user loses (gameStarted == false) , I need a way to remove all these nodes I've brought into the scene. I've tried to remove these nodes two ways, by simply saying ball.removeFromParent(), and also using the removeBalls function at the bottom. Both methods stopped future balls from entering the scene, but didn't remove the ones already in existence. If anybody has a way of doing this, I'd really appreciate it.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
 var create = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.createTargets()})
var wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(2)
var createAndWaitForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([create, wait])
self.runAction(createAndWaitForever)


}
      func createTargets() {

          ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"blueBlue")

                let randomx = Int(arc4random_uniform(370) + 165)
                ball.position = CGPoint(x: randomx, y: 1400)
                addChild(ball)

                let moveDown = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -1300), duration: 7)



            if gameStarted == false {

                ball.removeAllActions()

                ball.removeFromParent()

                removeBalls([ball])
            }

            if gameStarted && spawnReady {

                ball.runAction(moveDown)

                if ball.parent == nil {

                    addChild(ball)
                }     
            }  
            }

 func removeBalls(balls : [SKSpriteNode]) {

            for ball in balls {

            ball.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you keeping track of each **ball**? Do you have a **balls** array?

Do this:

1. Give a name to your `ball` nodes, say "ball"
2. Enumerate

## Swift

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("ball", usingBlock: {
    (node: SKNode!, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer <ObjCBool>) -> Void in 
    node.removeFromParent()
})
```

## Obj-C

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"ball" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
     [node removeFromParent];
 }];`
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I do not have an array to keep track of my nodes. I'd like to try your code but unfortunately I can't translate it to swift.